# Github Action using variable-substitution target and replace XML connectionStrings node

Tags: xml, github-actions

I am attempting to change a cnfgConnection.config > "connectionString" value using the following action and settings.

How do I target the connectionStrings > add > connectionString value?

```
- uses: microsoft/variable-substitution@v1 
   with:
       files: './Website/cnfgConnection.config'
   env:
          connectionStrings.add: "Data Source=prod.server.com;Initial Catalog=test;User ID=prod_tester;Password=xxxxxx"
```

Example XML file cnfgConnection.config

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="DefaultConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=test.server.com;Initial Catalog=test;User ID=tester;Password=xxxxxx" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the YAML use the following:

```
- run: echo "Variable Substitution"
        - uses: microsoft/variable-substitution@v1 
          with:
            files: './Website/cnfgConnection.config'
          env:
            connectionString: ${{ secrets.CONNSTRING_PROD }}
```

Then in Settings > secrets > actions > add secrets named CONNSTRING_PROD

Enter:

```
connectionString="Data Source=test.server.com;Initial Catalog=test;User ID=tester;Password=xxxxxx" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
```

[image]